# Where can I find the YAML file that governs my "Pages Build and Deployment" Job

Tags: javascript, github, yaml, mean, mern

Haven't touched my repro since 2017 and I've forgotten where the YAML or configuration file is for "Pages Build and Deployment" job is. The Github UI doesn't seem to point to a specific job(s) or a _config.yml that holds this together. I was hoping to share this with fledgling developer whose github set up has none of these jobs to help process html projects.

Any direction would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a YAML file under the directory `.github/workflows/`

Comment: Thanks this helped tremendously. Am I able to access this via Visual Studio Studio or Code. I can’t seem to touch that file via the IDE or Git